# Broken flair in election page, due to moderator having deleted his account

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, deleted-accounts, flair

In the [election page](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election) for the Philosophy site:

[image]

One image is broken (see red circle), because it refers to a moderator who has chosen to delete his account lately.

Comment: Red circle is not free hand ... :(

Comment: not reproducible in similar scenario on TWP: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election (Snow who won in 2018 deleted his account)

Comment: @rene I knew someone would say this... Well, you think it's not, but it is. See, I have a very steady hand and can draw perfect ellipsis using MS Paint. It took years of training, and I'm pretty upset that this get me this kind of remarks, instead of a round of applause.

Comment: Let's all praise your steady hand!

Comment: They have to be taken care of manually, apparently; at least, that's what had to happen on [Science Fiction & Fantasy in 2016](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8112/33591) ([second related link](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8107/33591)).

Comment: @Mithical yeah, those pages seem to be manually edited, causing [all kind of anomalies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354237/something-is-wrong-with-the-november-2015-moderator-election)

Comment: [The meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)

Comment: Election page is now fixed

Comment: @YaakovEllis - is this a one-off fix like Shog had done previously (see my previous comment above), or was there something done more permanently for when this happens? As the network gets older this is becoming a more frequent occurrence; is there anything in place to prevent this from being broken every time?

Comment: @Mithical one-off fix. The results are actually stored as html text in a db field. Changing it programmatically is not justified at this point. To fix it, we would have to add logic to the user deletion to parse all election results for their Id and replace it with something else. Doable but not worth it right now.