# Stub image for deleted moderator on localized sites

Tags: bug, status-review, election, localization, deleted-accounts

Disclaimer: I can't find the same situation for other sites, but I believe that all of non-English sites are affected (hence this BR should belong to MSE, but not individual per-site Meta). // end of disclaimer

In case when elected one day moderator deletes their own profile we will see the stub image ["USER REMOVED"](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10):

> [image: mod removed en]

It seems that for site with non-English interface we don't have that type of image. For instance, look [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1):

> [image: mod removed ru]

The better solution here is to generate the image according the string from translation available via traducir.win

Comment: It has nothing to do with the site being non-English. Per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342768/377214), it always becomes a broken image whenever a moderator deletes their profile, then staff swap it for a placeholder image. This placeholder has been inconsistent in the past - some older elections show "Departed" instead, some show "User Removed", and others show an archived copy of the user's flair before they deleted their profile - it's based on whichever staff member handles it at the time. (But again, this handling is completely manual.)

Comment: Related: [Broken flair in election page, due to moderator having deleted his account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340242/335251)